# CSS rule overriding custom rules for background-color

Tags: css, wordpress

I am encountering some issues with CSS rules on a website I am working at this moment.

It is using a custom theme based on WPBakery Visual Builder. Issue is, I need to edit the background color of a element. I have tried both:

- Editing the row background color in WPBakery. The issue is that it shows correctly in the editing panel, but not on the actual website.
- Adding custom CSS rules for that element.

Problem is, a stylesheet probably overrides my rules that I have set up. Explaining screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPAlO.jpg

Any ideas on solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Add more specificity to your element, for example:

```css
div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}

div.test{
  background:blue !important;
}

.test{
  background:red !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Without the `div` part in the selector the square would have taken the last css rule and apply it since they both would have same specificity same as in your case.

Comment: I have tried like all the possible combinations I thought of. Still not working. This is the element: https://imgur.com/a/6Jhm4vk

Comment: @IulianOancea and which is your class? The `.vc_custom_...` one creating a green background? If so I don't see it having any more specificity than before, please paste exactly which selector are you using

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is used `!important`, avoid doing this. But try to be more specific, for example: .parent-div .your-class { color: pink } ... and probably you must add also `!important`; But I recommend you to edit your theme and delete `!important` at least where you have problems. Also is important order of import styles.css, add a custom file and put it last in the  like:

```
<head>
<link rel="theme.css" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Browser will take the last declaration.

Comment: Which file should I add this into?

Comment: Search for header in your P theme and and a new css file and there put your style which you want to overwrite. I see your class names and it seems it's a generated styles. You don't have documentation for this theme?